# org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Could not open the specified zip entry source stream in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, excel, aws-lambda, apache-poi

I created a simple web app that uploads excel files (xlsx) to s3 bucket. For this to happen I created an AWS lambda function that will receive the file upload from the front end web app. Once received, my java application deployed in AWS lambda function will read the inputstream of the uploaded excel file. My code as below:

```
public class ExcelFileProcessor extends FileProcessor {

@Override
public void extract() throws IOException {
    try (Workbook wb = StreamingReader.builder()
            .rowCacheSize(100)
            .bufferSize(4096)
            .open(super.getInputStream())){

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(NumericConstant.ZERO);

        List<String[]> outerList = new ArrayList<>();

        sheet.forEach(row -> {

            List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();

            int startCellIndex = row.getFirstCellNum();
            int endCellIndex = row.getLastCellNum();

            for(int rw = startCellIndex; rw < endCellIndex; rw++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(rw, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
                innerList.add(cell.getStringCellValue().replace(StringConstant.NEXT_LINE_STRING, 
                        StringConstant.EMPTY_STRING).trim());
            }

            outerList.add(innerList.stream().toArray(String[]::new));
        });

        List<String[]> list = outerList;

        super.setRawData(list);

        DataHandler data = new DataHandler();
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(NumericConstant.ZERO);

        list.forEach(element -> {

            if(count.get() == NumericConstant.ZERO) {

                for(int i = NumericConstant.ZERO; i < element.length; i++) {
                    data.addColumn(String.valueOf(element[i]));
                }
            } else {
                data.addRow(element);
            }

            count.set(count.incrementAndGet());
        });

        super.setDataHandler(data);
    }
}
```

This is my service class

```
public class UploadService{

    public ResponseEntity<Object> processUpload(MultipartFile file, String delimiter) {

        FileProcessor processor = factory.getFileType(file.getContentType());

        processor.setFile(file);
        processor.setFileSize(file.getSize());
        processor.setDelimiter(delimiter);
        processor.setS3BucketName(s3Properties.getBucketName());
        processor.setTemPath(lambdaProperties.getDefaultFilepath());
        processor.setWritePath(s3Properties.getUploadPath().getPending());
        processor.setInputStream(file.getInputStream());
        processor.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        processor.extract();
        processor.write();
        processor.clean();
   }
}
```

my endpoint class

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class UploadEndpoint{

@Autowired
private UploadService service;

@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Object> processUploadedFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, 
        @RequestPart("delimiter") String delimiter) {
    logger.debug("processUploadedFile endpoint invoked..");
    return service.processUpload(file, delimiter);
}
}
```

my Upload.html

```
    <form class="md-form" method="post" action="https://xxxxxxxxxxx/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="uploadModalLongTitle">Upload Tool</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="file-field big">
                    <a class="btn-floating btn-lg white darken-2 mt-0 float-left">
                        <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <input type="file" name="file" 
                            accept=".csv,.txt,.xlsx,.dat"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto">Upload</button>
                <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" title="Choose a delimiter" 
                    name="delimiter" id="select-delimiter">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The purpose of using StreamingReader is for uploaded large excel files. The fullstack error I encounter is as below:

```
  01:05:29
  org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Could not open the specified zip 
  entry source stream
  
  01:05:29
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:216) ~[poi- 
  ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
  
  01:05:29
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:198) ~[poi- 
  ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
  
  01:05:29
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:172) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
  
  01:05:29
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:153) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
  
  01:05:29
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:277) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
  
  01:05:29
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:186) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
  
  01:05:29
  at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.init(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:113) ~[xlsx-streamer-2.1.0.jar:na]
  
  01:05:29
  at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.init(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:91) ~[xlsx-streamer-2.1.0.jar:na]
  
  01:05:29
  at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader$Builder.open(StreamingReader.java:251) ~[xlsx-streamer-2.1.0.jar:na]
```


      01:05:29
      at 
      01:05:29
          Caused by: java.io.IOException: ZIP entry size is too large or invalid
          
          01:05:29
          at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveFakeEntry.(ZipArchiveFakeEntry.java:43) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
          
          01:05:29
          at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:53) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]

01:05:29
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.openZipEntrySourceStream(ZipPackage.java:214) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]

01:05:29
... 59 common frames omitted

I can't solve the problem, I already searched for 2 whole days for a solution but I still encounter the error.. can somebody help me with this?

Comment: The exception is thrown on `.open(super.getInputStream())` and mainly is `Caused by: java.io.IOException: ZIP entry size is too large or invalid`. So where is `super.getInputStream()` coming from and what exactly is it doing?  And where is the "the uploaded excel file" located?

Comment: @AxelRichter super.getInputStream() is called from the parent abstract class of this class.

`**public ResponseEntity<Object> processUpload(MultipartFile file, String delimiter) {
  
ValidationUtils.validateFile(file);
FileProcessor processor = factory.getFileType(file.getContentType());
processor.setInputStream(file.getInputStream());

}**`

the file is from the MultipartFile object from the webpage.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide additional information there and not in a comment. Also you have not answered my questions. What does `super.getInputStream()` return? The `InputStream` which was got from `MultipartFile.getInputStream()`? Sure this really contains the bytes of a `*.xlsx` file? Sure it fully contains those?

Comment: Sorry I updated my question for additional details.. and yes you are correct, the super.getInputStream() returns the InputStream from the MultipartFile.getInputStream().